# React does not wait for Redux state change to finish before rendering a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building simple authorization application. I am using MERN stack + Redux and basic logic is that after certain user successfully logs in a cookie ( httpOnly ) with jwt token as value is being stored inside of a browser. Now after user logs in I dispatch an login action after which I redirect user to **Home Page**, so inside **Login Page** I have this :

```
  const handleFormSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(login_action(loginFormData));
        history.push("/");
     }
  };
```

Now inside of a Home Page I dispatch an action called **get_cookie_action** which will make an Api call to a NodeJs backend ( where I check if jwt inside of a cookie is valid ) and return true or false depending of cookie state. This is get_cookie_action :

```
   export const get_cookie_action = () => async (dispatch) =>{
      try {
            dispatch({type:'GET_COOKIE_REQUEST'});
            const { data } = await api.get_cookie();
            dispatch({
                      type : 'GET_COOKIE_LOGGED_IN',
                      payload : data
                    });
            } catch (error) {
               dispatch({
                          type : 'GET_COOKIE_LOGGED_OUT',
                          payload : error.response.data
               });
              }
            };
```

This is **get_cookie_reducer** :

```
   export const get_cookie_reducer = ( cookie = {} , action ) =>{
switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_COOKIE_REQUEST' :
        return {
            loading : true
        }
    case 'GET_COOKIE_LOGGED_IN' :
        return {
            loading : false,
            cookie : action.payload
        }
    case 'GET_COOKIE_LOGGED_OUT' :
        return {
            loading : false,
            cookie : action.payload
        }
    default : 
        return cookie;
};
```

In **Home Page** I dispatch an action for getting a cookie value through **get_cookie_action** and check for that cookie, so I have this inside of a **Home Page** :

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(get_cookie_action());
},[]);
```

and above I have:

```
const cookie_info = useSelector( state => state.is_user_logged_in );
const { cookie, loading } = cookie_info;
```

And I return this :

```
    return (
        <>
            {
              typeof cookie !== 'undefined'
              ?  
               (
                   loading
                   ?
                   <h1>loading...loading...loading...</h1>
                   :
                   (
                       cookie
                       ?
                       <h1> You are logged in ! </h1>
                       :
                       <Redirect to="login"/>
                   )
               )
              :
              null
            }
    </>
);
```

The main problem is that after user logs in he cannot access **Home Page** because

```
 <Redirect to="login"/>
```

is being *fired* immediately and React is not waiting for a cookie state to change from {} which is initial state of a cookie in reducers to true.

Comment: You can check if login_action was successful or not, and if it was successful than do ```history.push("/");```.

Comment: @SanskarBansal Not working either

Comment: Can you show me your whole Login Page Code if possible.

Comment: An empty object is a truthy value, so if your variable `cookie` is an empty object, then `cookie ? ... ` will always evaluate to true.